# Android client with node.js serer

Tags: android, node.js, authentication, server

Is it possible to use passport + jwt + bcrypt for authentication if I need to connect my node.js server with android app ? Or I no need use passport ?

Comment: You can use whatever packages you find you need on the server side, all your Android app needs to know is the type of authentication you're using. The server's implementation only matters to the server.

Comment: @Tim McCabe, thank you